# Is Domain Driven Design (and Aggregate) slow?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, domain-driven-design

I'm working with Entity Framework with a DDD approach for a while, but now I've some question about the performance for the queries: ***Every time I load and Aggregate from a AggregateRoot Repository, I load the entire AggregateRoot with all the columns and Includes instead of loading just load the columns that I need***. This is, of course, slow.

Let's me explain with an Example:

```cs
public class User : AggregateRoot {
  public Guid Id { get; private set; }
  public string Name { get; private set; }
  public string Surname { get; private set; }
  public int Followers { get; private set; }
  public List<SomeOtherEntity> SomeOtherEntities { get; private set; }

  //...
  public void IncreaseFollowers() 
  {
    Followers++;
  }
}
```

```cs
//Repository
public class UserRepository : IUserRepository {
  //...injections
  public User GetById(Guid id) {
     return _database
                .Users
                .Include(x => x.SomeOtherEntities)
                .FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

So, in my handlers (I'm using CQRS pattern), every time I need to get a User Entity, I've to load the entire entity with all the Include, without any optimization such as `.AsNoTracking()` or others.

For example, If I need to increment the followers for a User, I should do something like this:

```cs
public class IncreareUserFollowerCommandHandler : IHandler<.,.> {
    //..injections

    public void Handle() 
    {
        var user = _userRepo.GetById(request.Id);

        user.IncreaseFollowers();
        _userRepo.Update(user);
        _userRepo.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

**So the question is: how to coexist DDD and EF? Probably the problem is the generic nature of the Repository for the AggregateRoot?** In this example I just need to increment a number, so, if I don't use a Repository or an DDD approach I can just load the column that I need and update just that column, without load the entire Aggregate every time!

Thanks a lot for any suggestions! :)

Comment: Here's an article that claims that repository pattern isn't useful in Entity Framework: https://www.thereformedprogrammer.net/is-the-repository-pattern-useful-with-entity-framework-core/. It might shine some light on your question.